# How to build a dynamic tile in a Mango App

Tags: tiles, windows-phone-7.1

I'm building a WP7 (Mango) app that reads data from a SQL Server local database that contains events happened on a certain date. I would like to implement a live tile that shows the number of events happened on the current date and, when clicked, goes to the details page (not the home page).

I've read that it can be done using secondary tiles, I would like to know if I can do it using the "primary" live tile of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can update secondary and primary tiles in the same way.

There is an example on how to do this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx#BKMK_PushAndTiles